# Assign a whole row as None: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Create a new dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 6], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield']) df
```

Show it's value:

```
df
            max_speed  shield
cobra               1       2
viper               4       6
sidewinder          7       8
```

Now i want to assign the whole first row as `10`.

```
df.iloc[0:1,] = 10
df
            max_speed  shield
cobra              10      10
viper               4       6
sidewinder          7       8
```

Assign the whole first row as `None`.

```
df.iloc[0:1,] = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 190, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 471, in _setitem_with_indexer
    info_idx = indexer[info_axis]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Why can't assign a whole row as None with just one expression?

```
df.iloc[0,0] = None
df.iloc[0,1] = None
```

The two statements can assign the row as `None`,why can't write only one expression such as `df.iloc[0:1,] = 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is add `:` for select all columns:

```
df.iloc[0:1,:] = None
print (df)
            max_speed  shield
cobra             NaN     NaN
viper             4.0     6.0
sidewinder        7.0     8.0
```

Or also omit `,`:

```
df.iloc[0:1] = None
print (df)
            max_speed  shield
cobra             NaN     NaN
viper             4.0     6.0
sidewinder        7.0     8.0
```

But in my opinion reason why `df.iloc[0:1, ] = None` failed should be bug.

Comment: Why `df.iloc[0:1,] = 10` can work,instead of  `df.iloc[0:1,] = None`?